# Add fields in advanced block setting

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Trying to build a custom block with settings in `Advanced block settings` tab which opens in the sidebar on RHS...

WordPress' default blocks seem to have settings there but unfortunately can't find it documented anywhere...

Any pointers would be really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2018/08/16** The inspector controls links seem to have moved as Gutenberg developed since I originally wrote this.

The rough idea is that everything you add as a child of `<InspectorControls>`, will be at the sidebar when the user focuses on your block:

```
return (
    <InspectorControls> 
        {/* Whatever is inside this block will be displayed on the sidebar */} . 
    </InspectorControls>
        {/* Whatever is outside, will be displayed on the editor as usual */}
)
```

Take a look at this article for reference:

https://medium.com/@eudestwt/how-to-make-an-editable-wordpress-gutenberg-block-with-inspector-controls-on-the-sidebar-8779f4eddf8e

---

I think what you're looking for are Gutenberg's [InspectorControls](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/index.js). I have found an example from [lucasstark/gutenberg-gravityforms](https://github.com/lucasstark/gutenberg-gravityforms/blob/master/assets/js/block.js#L56-L67) that shows them in use.

Digging through the Gutenberg I have found the following options but no official docs (best they have is [this](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/block-controls-toolbars-and-inspector/#inspector)) showing off their usage:

- [`InspectorControls.CheckboxControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/checkbox-control/index.js)
- [`InspectorControls.RadioControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/radio-control/index.js)
- [`InspectorControls.RangeControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/range-control/index.js)
- [`InspectorControls.SelectControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/select-control/index.js)
- [`InspectorControls.TextControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/text-control/index.js)
- [`InspectorControls.TextareaControl`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/blocks/inspector-controls/textarea-control/index.js)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @GavinSimpson, I've updated my answer with a reference article I now use.

Comment: Looks like I must forget about ES5, and dive into ESNext. Thanks for the answer update.